# Lagrange multipliers. Extreme point of funtion in cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have the function : $$f(x,y,z)= x+y^2+3z^2$$ and I am asked to find the minimum and maximum of it in the cylinder $x^2+y^2 \leq4$.

firstly I dont understand why $x^2+y^2 \leq4$ is called cylinder and not circle, secondly how I can build my lagrange function with constraint that is expressed in inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+y^2 \leq4$ is a cylinder not a circle because you are working in the three dimensional plane plane, see how your main function is in terms of $x,y,z$. This would be a circle going all along the z-axis (you can imagine in as a non-ending infinite can), a cylinder in three dimensions always has $2$ variables, and it goes along the third missing one. 
To draw cylinders in three dimensions draw the function given (the circle in your case, could be any curve in general) then extend it so it goes all along the missing variable.

Concerning the set-up, use the following:

$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-4\leq0$ (constraint)

$f(x,y,z)=x+y^2+3z^2$ (function)

We set-up and solve the following system of equations:

$\nabla\vec f=\lambda\nabla\vec g$   ($\nabla$ means the gradient)

$g(x,y,z)=0$

$\nabla\vec f=1i\vec +2y\vec j+6z\vec k$

$\nabla\vec g=2x\vec i+2y\vec j$

so we get the following system:

$2x=\lambda$ $(1)$

$2y=\lambda 2y$ $(2)$

$0=\lambda0=0$ $(3)$

$x^2+y^2-4 \leq 4$ $(4)$

You might get multiple coordinates, all coordinates you will get will represent the points where there is an extreme value. 
To check which gives you a maximum and which gives you a minimum you should plug them in $f(x,y,z)$ and see compare the values. 
Pay attention that you might get points which aren't on the cylinder, in this case you should rule them out.

Additional tip based on personal experience:

Usually the the challenge in Lagrange problems is to identify the function and constraint. Example of keywords that might help in identifying the constraint: "lying on the surface", "can be inscribed in", "surface area equal to S(some number)", etc.... Of course other words can be used and you should always think about what you choose as a constraint, but these might be good as a hint.

Comment: How I can solve this system of equations? how I should handle this inequality?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

First, $x^2+y^2\le 4$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ is a cylinder.
Second, introducing a slack variable to transform the inequality into an equality making

$$
L = x+y^2+3z^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2-4+\epsilon^2)
$$

we have the stationary condition

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 \lambda  x+1 \\
 2 \lambda  y+2 y \\
 6 z \\
 \epsilon^2+x^2+y^2-4 \\
 2\epsilon \lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving for $x,y,\lambda,\epsilon$ we obtain

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
f & x & y & z & \lambda & \epsilon^2\\
 -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 \frac{17}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 \frac{17}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{15}}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here $\epsilon = 0$ means that the extrema are located at the restriction boundary.